# Asynchronous Programming in C# with Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, stringbuilder

I started to learn about async programming and I stumbled across this problem. I call these functions over an Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

I'm expecting to get file content form `ReadText` method, but all I get back is "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"

So question is what's wrong with my code and which line should I fix?

Sadly I can't figure out where my problem is because I am looking at this peace of code for quite some time now.

I thought because I get back the time of the object and not the object itself that my ReadText method is wrong, but I don't see where. It seems there is something wrong with my part below the Stringbuilder or the way I made these methods async.

If you wonder why I used two methods is to get known with await and calling async Task methods. I also tried making the method a Tast method but that only resulted in even more problems.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
    public async void ReadFile()
    {
        string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filePath + " not found", "File Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string text = await ReadText(filePath);                 
                txtContents.Text = text;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
    {
        Task Readfile = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                sb.Append(text);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
        );

        await Readfile;

        return Readfile.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Why do you wrap reading from file into `Task.Run` at all?

Comment: To get a value from a `Task<TValue>` you need to let the task complete or block (eg. the `Result` property will block). A `Task` instance is a link to the work being done; not the result. Once you have the result of the task then you can use it for further processing.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. But Radin Gospodinov's Answer helped me just perfectly. 

My Problem was not getting the result I wanted from my Task. As I found out I didn't have to use Task.Run in my ReadText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Task.Run for reading from the stream, there is convenient method ReadAsync that you can await:

```
 public async Task ReadFile() {
      string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";

      if (File.Exists(filePath) == false) {
        MessageBox.Show(filePath + " not found", "File Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
      } else {
        try {
          string text = await ReadText(filePath);
          txtContents.Text = text;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
      }
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath) {

      using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
          FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
          bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true)) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        int numRead;
        while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
          string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
          sb.Append(text);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
      }

    }
```

Also avoid async void is not recommended, try to avoid that.Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started.
[Best practice for async methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a `string`, so make `Readfile` a `Task<string>`:

```
Task<string> Readfile = Task.Run<string>( ... )
```

Then you want to return `Readfile.Result;`, not `Readfile.ToString();`
But you can write this simpler:

```
return await Readfile;
```

or even:

```
return await Task.Run<string>( ... )
```